# How is Elastic Search sorting when no sort option specified and no search query specified

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder how Elastic search is sorting (on what field) when no search query is specified (I just filter on documents) and no sort option specified.  It looks like sorting is than random ...  Default sort order is _score, but score is always 1 when you do not specify a search query ...

Answer (score 3):

You got it right. Its then more or less random with score being 1. You still get consistent results as far as I remember. You have the "same" when you get results in SQL but don't specify `ORDER BY`.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to 'flip' the order of those randomness sorting?

Comment: @lior-magen Do you mean reversing it? I don't think it is possible since there is no actual sorting. You can do it in your handler dealing with the response from elasticsearch and simply reverse the results you get. If you want consistent results, specify an order and then you can also specify the direction.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone may see this post even it posted over 6 yrs ago..

When you wanna know how elasticsearch calculate its own score known as `_score`, you can use the `explain option`.

I suppose that your query(with filter & without search) might like this more or less (but the point is making the `explain option true`) :

```js
    POST /goods/_search
    {
        "explain": true, 
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "maker_name": "nike"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As running this, you will notice that the `_explaination` of each hits describes as below :

```js
    "_explanation" : {
        "value" : 1.0,
        "description" : "ConstantScore(maker_name:nike)",
        "details" : [ ]
    }
```

which means ES gave `constant score` to all of the hits.

So to answer the question, "yes".
The results are sorted kinda randomly because all the filtered results  have same (constant) score without any search query.

By the way, enabling an explain option is more helpful when you use search queries. You will see how ES calculates the score and will understand the reason why it returns in that order.

Answer (score 1):

Score is mainly used for sorting, Score is calculated by lucene score calculating  using several constraints,For more info **[refer here](http://technyvorous.wordpress.com/elastic-search/scoring-in-elastic-search/)** .

Comment: score is main factor of sorting. It's right. But what the OP is asking from is what does make priority when not using search_term and all results scored 1.