# Average of field in nested mapping for elasticssearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I unable to get the average of cpuaveload filed.

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "kpi" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "kpi" : {
        "properties" : {
          "date" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "kpi" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "CpuAverageLoad" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "HaGroupId" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "LbGroupId" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "MemFree" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "MemUsed" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "NodeId" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "NodeType" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "State" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "Static_limit" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/kpi/_search?size=0&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "from": 0,   "size": 10,
    "sort":[
        {"date" : {"order" : "desc"}}
    ],
    "stored_fields": [],
    "query": {
      "nested": {
      "path": "kpi",
      "query": {
        "match": {"kpi.NodeType" : "cs"}
      },
      "inner_hits": {
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "kpi" : {
          "nested" : {
            "path" : "kpi"
          },
        "aggs" : {
          "avg_price" : { "avg" : { "field" : "kpi.CpuAverageLoad" } }
        }
       }
     }      
    }
  }
}'
```

When i execute I get the below error:

> "[nested] query does not support [aggs]" 
>   type : "parsing_exception",
>   reason : "[nested] query does not support [aggs]", 
>   line : 16, col : 16

I need to get the average of `CpuAveLoad`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you included the `aggs` inside the `query`. The `inner_hits` is also defined in a wrong position. This should work:

```
{
   "from": 0,   "size": 10,
   "sort":[{
      "date" : {"order" : "desc"}
   }],
   "stored_fields": [],
   "query": {
      "nested" : {
         "path" : "kpi",
         "query" : {
            "match" : { "kpi.NodeType" : "type_a" }
         },
         "inner_hits" : {
         }
      }
    },


  "aggs": {   
     "kpi": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "kpi"
         },
         "aggs" : {
             "average-agg" : {
                 "avg" : { "field" : "kpi.CpuAverageLoad" }
              }

         }
     }   
   }
}
```

The solution was tested with elasticsearch 5-6. Please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Sure, will test and confirm today as i have setup issues

Comment: The query is working well but
1. average is taking for all hits but my expectation is to take only for the matched queries i.e..
For the 1st 10 'nodetype = type_a' records

Comment: Ideally average should be taken based on the match query (i.e from for form the latest 10 records   ) I hope i am clear, if not let me know

Comment: I don't think, that you can apply an aggregation query only for the current page of results.  At least I haven't seen anything similar to that.

Comment: In general if i select  the items from 1 to 10 (using from() & to())then will it automatically give me the latest 10 items or will it pick randomly 10 iteams. Because  i dont have any date/creation date in source field.

Comment: if no default sort criteria are set, then the results will be sorted according to the score -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919296/how-is-elastic-search-sorting-when-no-sort-option-specified-and-no-search-query

Comment: okay, so if i dont have any nested query and it is just a plan query. Then is possible to have sort & avaerage in query? i.e can i sort the doc based on Date and in the top 10 hits can i calculate the average of certain field?

Comment: My Mapping:
_italic_ **bold** `
{
  "cscfcounter" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "cscfcounter" : {
        "properties" : {
          "CpuAverageLoad" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "Static_limit" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "date" : {
            "type" : "date"
          }}}}}}
`
I need to get the average of 'CpuAverageLoad' of latest 10 doc(sorted by date).
i tried below but vain
{
 "from": 0,   "size": 10,
 "sort":[{ "date" : {"order" : "desc"}}],
  "aggs" : { "avg_grade" : { "avg" : { "field" : "CpuAverageLoad" } }}}'

Comment: This is another question. I suggest that we close this one and then you search if there is already a question with your new requirements.  If not you can post a new question

Comment: sure, i will create a new query., kindly check